# save current_user.id into another column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

currently I have the model commodity_group, there are created_by, and updated_by columns in it. It belongs to user, and one user will have commodity_groups. Now, I want to whenever a user created a commodity group, his id will be saved into the created_by, and whenever somebody update a commodity group, his id will be saved into the field update_by. 
At the moment, i get this error:

> unknown attribute 'user_id' for CommodityGroup.

basically, I don't want to add the column user_id to the commodity_group table since it is the same with the column created_by. Therefore, could somebody guide me here a little bit. Here are my files:

**commodity_groups_controller.rb:**

```
class CommodityGroupsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_commodity_group, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /commodity_groups
  def index
    @commodity_groups = CommodityGroup.all
  end

  # GET /commodity_groups/1
  def show
  end

  # GET /commodity_groups/new
  def new
    @commodity_group = current_user.commodity_groups.build
  end

  # GET /commodity_groups/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /commodity_groups
  def create
    @commodity_group = current_user.commodity_groups.build(commodity_group_params)


    if @commodity_group.save
      redirect_to commodity_groups_path, notice: init_message(:success, t('message.new_success', page_name: t('page_name.commodity_group')))
    else
      redirect_to new_commodity_group_path, notice: init_message(:error, t('message.new_error', page_name: t('page_name.commodity_group')))
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /commodity_groups/1
  def update
    if @commodity_group.update(commodity_group_params)
      redirect_to @commodity_group, notice: 'Commodity group was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  # DELETE /commodity_groups/1
  def destroy
    @commodity_group.destroy
    redirect_to commodity_groups_url, notice: 'Commodity group was successfully destroyed.'
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_commodity_group
      @commodity_group = CommodityGroup.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def commodity_group_params
      params[:commodity_group]
    end
end
```

**commodity_group.rb**:

```
class CommodityGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :code, use: :history

  belongs_to :user_created,
             class_name: 'User',
             primary_key: :id,
             foreign_key: :created_by
  belongs_to :user_updated,
             class_name: 'User',
             primary_key: :id,
             foreign_key: :updated_by

  validates_presence_of :code
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :user
end
```

**user.rb:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  include Filterable

  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :history
  has_secure_password
  acts_as_paranoid

  has_many :activities
  has_many :pricing_histories
  has_many :commodity_groups
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CommodityGroup is searching for `user_id` in `commodity_groups` table.

You need to specify that in the `User` model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  include Filterable

  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :history
  has_secure_password
  acts_as_paranoid

  has_many :activities
  has_many :pricing_histories
  has_many :commodity_groups_created, class_name: 'CommodityGroup',
                                      foreign_key: :created_by
  has_many :commodity_groups_updated, class_name: 'CommodityGroup',
                                      foreign_key: :updated_by
end
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Even though I still couldn't save the current_user.id to created_by column in the table commodity_group, I still want to mark your solution as the best one. I will make another question for my current problem. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

you've got the foreign_key on the `CommodityGroup` side, you just need to add it to the User side as well and you should be good to go eg:

```
has_many :commodity_groups, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :created_by
```

(you may need to jigger with the details to figure out what else you need to add, but this will basically give you the idea on how to solve it)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. So, it means that I have to add the created_by field to the user table also?

Comment: Nope - the created_by field already exists on the other table... but by default Rails will use the class name to figure out the fieldname and in this instance it will be looking for a field named `user_id` - which doesn't exist on your other table... so you have to tell it what the field name really is

Comment: yes, I got what you mean. Actually, Mr. Deepack has given the solution that I am looking for, and thank you very much. Have a nice day.